# Swapping selected texts in VSCode

Tags: visual-studio-code

Consider I have the following code:

```
if (a === 'some condition') 
  return true
else
  return false
```

If I want to swap the returns, i.e. `true` and `false`, I select them, but then is there any keyboard shortcut or key binding to swap my selections?

Comment: FWIW, if this language is like Python, you could simply `return a === 'some condition'` and swap with `return not ...` or `return ! ...`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use this [Transpose plugin for VSCode](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=v4run.transpose)

PS - [This is the feature request thread](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/12435) from which I got to know about this plugin

Comment: There's now a plugin called Swap that works pretty good.

Answer (score 1):

Use [Any Swap](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=wolray.any-swap) (the most installed) plugin for swapping text in Visual Studio code

Comment: *transpose* (from the [top answer](/a/44692349/4518341)) has 18k installs vs Any Swap's 10k.

Comment: It's worth adding that Any Swap does a basic AST parse of the source code, so it can (somewhat) intelligently move text around relative to operators.

Answer (score 0):

The [**Swap**](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=fausto95.swap) extension should work as you intended.

---

#### Keyboard Shortcut:

- Windows: `CTRL+ALT+8`
- Mac: `CMD+OPTION+8`

Comment: didnt work for windows